# Compartir entityManager entre proyectos

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un proyecto en el cual estoy usando spring y persistence. Estoy manejando `@Transactional`, pero existe un proyecto externo el cual se va a utilizar para operaciones comunes en la base de datos y le estoy enviando el `entityManager` con el cual estoy ejecutando las operaciones de mis DAOs, al ocurrir un error al final del método que ejecuta todas las operaciones, el resultado esperado es que las transacciones hagan rollback, pero la transacción en mi proyecto externo no ejecuta rollback.

Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute el rollback en todo el servicio cuando ocurra un error.

Ejemplo

**DAO:**

```
@Repository
public class MyDAO{
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PORTALPU")
   protected EntityManager entityManager;

   @Autowired
   private externalProjectDAO externalProjectDAO;

   public void save(Object obj){

         entityManager.persist(obj);

         //Some other persist action in external DAO
         externalProjectDAO(entityManager,obj);

         int i=10/0; //Here the entityManager must make a rollback
   }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Transactional
public class ServiceClass{

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDao;

    public void save(Object obj){
         myDAO.save(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente cuando dices: `" le estoy enviando el entityManager"`?

Comment: Tengo mi objeto de entityManager en mi proyecto A, con el cual ejecuto mis transacciones en este proyecto, y este mismo objeto se lo envío a mi proyecto externo para que lo utilice para realizar las transacciones de base de datos que le corresponden

Comment: A la hora de ejecutar no tiene sentido hablar de "proyecto". En tiempo de ejecución, y dentro de una aplicación, no importa cómo se compiló cada class o cómo se empaquetó cada jar de los que están accesibles en el classpath. De hecho en Java no existe ni siquiera el concepto de proyecto, son "inventos" que son útiles para los IDEs y demás pero nada más.

Comment: Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, dices que hay un ejecutable A y ahora van a crear otro ejecutable B (entiéndase por ejecutable una aplicación escrita en Java que corre en su propio proceso de sistema operativo, ya sea un jar, una aplicación Web, etc) y lo que quieres lograr es que si en el proyecto A se ejecuta un rollback entonces en B también se ejecute un rollback, ¿cierto? De ser así, déjame decirte que no se puede lograr.

Comment: No son ejecutables independientes, es un ejecutable A que utiliza un jar B, como dice @SJuan76, están dentro de la misma MV. Me parece que si puedo hacer lo que requiero pero estoy implementando mal la manera indicarl la transaccionabilidad. Si me queda, les aviso en estaba cometiendo el error